# How to make a link a period of time available php

Tags: php, email, hash, email-verification

I want to make a sign up and login system. I have already a sign up page with a verification mail, but I want that the verification link a couple of hours can be clikked. Example if the click on the link about 5 hours than the mail is active, but if the click the mail verification link is clicked about 6 hours that then the email is not activated. How do I do this?

Comment: This is way too broad a question and tend to attract answers that may not suit you, or that you will keep commenting as to how it all works and what code(s) you should use. Keep on researching this; the answers to all of your questions exist on the web.

Comment: Looks like you need to learn more about what is expected of users here. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do this.

The first way is by using a timestamp to determine when the validation key has been issued, and once a user attempts to use it, you check if the current date surpasses the time limit (based on the issue timestamp), and eventually you validate it.

Another way would be using a JWT which has the expiration timestamp in it.

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232) Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.

Comment: Additionally, this answer doesn't actually solve their problem as it is also too broad. This is a perfect example of why these questions *can't* be answered.

Answer (score 1):

As you send email, make an entry in db of current timestamp, and when user open that email and click to activate verify if the time not exceeded with the mail send time + 5 hours.

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232) Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.

Comment: @D-Pachauri : sounds more like a comment...